# make install: cannot run strip: No such file or directory

Tags: make

```
root@server:~/shc-3.8.9# make install
***     Installing shc and shc.1 on /usr/local
***     Do you want to continue? y
install -c -s shc /usr/local/bin/
install: cannot run strip: No such file or directory
install: strip process terminated abnormally
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

I don't use `make install` often. Can someone tell me how to fix it? :)

/edit1:
This error actually occured befor the one I posted above, sorry if that's confusing.. (I tried to bypass the error below with "cp shc-3.8.9.c shc", but then the error above occured. So now that I installed "binutils", and repeated the install proccess, I get this error)

```
root@server:~/shc-3.8.9# make
cc -Wall  shc.c -o shc
make: cc: Command not found
make: *** [shc] Error 127
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to install and what version of Ubuntu are you on? A link to what you are trying to install would be helpful.

Comment: I'm trying to install shc-3.8.9 and I tried to follow this guide: http://www.liudongkai.com/articles/2013/10/14/1381715536639.html
I use Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: It never compiled , you need to install gcc and the dependencies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`make` tries to call the program `strip` which isn't installed.

Install the package `binutils`

Comment: thx, I edited my post. I guess another error occured :p